# php filtrar dados dentro do while

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldades em filtrar dentro de um while os dados que obtenho de uma base de dados. Estou a escrever HTML + PHP gerar o layout e para obter os dados da base dados sqlite.

Tabela: entradas
select * from entradas ORDER BY data;

```
numero  nome     data
4       Manuel   2018-11-17
6       Rui      2018-11-17
6       Rui      2018-11-17
2       Raul     2018-11-17
2       Raul     2018-11-17
2       Raul     2018-11-17
3       Pedro    2018-11-17
3       Pedro    2018-11-17
2       Raul     2018-11-18
4       Manuel   2018-11-18
6       Rui      2018-11-19
6       Rui      2018-11-19
2       Raul     2018-11-19
2       Raul     2018-11-19
```

A minha dificuldade é conseguir com o HTML e PHP filtrar e agrupar os dados desta forma mas com umas condições, se o nome e a data são as mesmas crio e  junto em um select menu, se for diferente na data ou no nome crio um novo select menu.
exemplo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <body>

    <select>
      <option value="x">Manuel 2018-11-17</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option value="x">Rui 2018-11-17</option>
      <option value="x">Rui 2018-11-17</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option value="x">Raul 2018-11-17</option>
      <option value="x">Raul 2018-11-17</option>
      <option value="x">Raul 2018-11-17</option>
    </select>
...
 <select>
      <option value="x">Rui 2018-11-19</option>
      <option value="x">Rui 2018-11-19</option>
    </select>
...    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: E qual a utilidade disso, parece meio sem sentido.

Comment: Lamento se de alguma forma ficou sem sentido, mas foi a forma rápida que consegui para explicar o que pretendia fazer. Na realidade nao estou a usar o select menu mas sim gerar varias listview com forms usando o JQM  de forma que possa processar a informação lá contida. [imagem](https://i.postimg.cc/JnyGr3Lq/Captura-de-ecr-2018-11-18-s-11-14-33.png)

Comment: Pois então, faça a pergunta "com a realidade" pois caso contrário corre o risco da pergunta ser fechada além de ganhares uns votos negativos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem certeza que você deseja ter duas `option` iguais dentro do `select`? Não faz muito sentido. Se sim, fiz um exemplo abaixo que se encaixa do que necessita.

Basicamente foi feito o mapeamento da lista de registros retornados do banco de dados e criados os elementos html para eles.

```
<?php

$registros = array(
    (object) ['numero' => 4, 'nome' => 'Manuel', 'data' => '2018-11-17'],
    (object) ['numero' => 6, 'nome' => 'Rui', 'data' => '2018-11-17'],
    (object) ['numero' => 6, 'nome' => 'Rui', 'data' => '2018-11-17'],
    (object) ['numero' => 2, 'nome' => 'Raul', 'data' => '2018-11-17'],
    (object) ['numero' => 2, 'nome' => 'Raul', 'data' => '2018-11-17'],
    (object) ['numero' => 2, 'nome' => 'Raul', 'data' => '2018-11-17'],
    (object) ['numero' => 3, 'nome' => 'Pedro', 'data' => '2018-11-17'],
    (object) ['numero' => 3, 'nome' => 'Pedro', 'data' => '2018-11-17'],
    (object) ['numero' => 2, 'nome' => 'Raul', 'data' => '2018-11-18'],
    (object) ['numero' => 2, 'nome' => 'Raul', 'data' => '2018-11-18'],
    (object) ['numero' => 4, 'nome' => 'Manuel', 'data' => '2018-11-18'],
    (object) ['numero' => 6, 'nome' => 'Rui', 'data' => '2018-11-19'],
    (object) ['numero' => 6, 'nome' => 'Rui', 'data' => '2018-11-19'],
    (object) ['numero' => 2, 'nome' => 'Raul', 'data' => '2018-11-19'],
    (object) ['numero' => 2, 'nome' => 'Raul', 'data' => '2018-11-19']
);

function mapeiaRegistros($registros)
{
    // Como deve ser identificado pelo nome e data é feito o mapeamento desses dados ao invés do objeto
    // Observação: caso o usuário precise do numero basta apenas colocar o $r->numero na frente do $r->nome e concatenar
    $mapear = function($r) {return $r->nome . ' ' . $r->data;};
    $registros = array_count_values((array_map($mapear, $registros)));
    return $registros;
}

$registros = mapeiaRegistros($registros);

?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR"> 
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     </head>
     <body>
         <div id="dados"></div>
     </body>
     <script>

        var div = document.createElement('div');

        <?php
             foreach($registros as $nomeData => $contagem)
             {
        ?>      
                var select = document.createElement("select");
        <?php
                for($i = 0; $i < $contagem; $i++)
                {
        ?>
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.id = '<?=$i?>';
                    option.text = '<?=$nomeData?>';
                    option.value = '<?=$nomeData?>';
                    select.appendChild(option);
        <?php   
                }
        ?>
                div.appendChild(select);
                div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        <?php    
             }
         ?>

         document.getElementById("dados").innerHTML = div.innerHTML;

     </script>
 </html>
```

Imagem do resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas como aplicar construir o array $registros no while que tenho?  `while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ) {

   }`

Comment: Dependendo do que você está usando você pode receber os dados como objeto e depois inserir ele na variávei registros e, portanto, remover esse while, como apresentei. Por exemplo, se estiver usando PDO pode usar o $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); e depois tratar de acordo com a variável $registro espera.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você queira possa ser feito com comparações simples e um laço `for`, lógica auto-explicativa, porém não faz muito sentido, pois todas as `option` tem o mesmo HTML interno, como você vai diferencia-las?

`select * from entradas ORDER BY data, nome`

```
$select = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($entradas); $i++) {

    $select .= '<select>';
    for ($j = $i; $entradas[$i]['nome'] == ($entradas[$j]['nome'] ?? ''); $j++) {
        $select .= "<option value='{$entradas[$j]['numero']}'>{$entradas[$j]['nome']} {$entradas[$j]['data']}</option>";
    }
    $select .= '</select>';

    $i = $j-1;
}

echo $select;
```